# Как отобразить в iframe страницу, запросив ее по особому `url` и отправив параметры методом `POST`?

Tags: html, html5, javascript

Доброго времени суток!
Ситуация такова...  
Надо внутрь iframe поместить страницу. Но для того, чтобы не возникло ошибки при запросе той страницы, надо обязательно в нее посылать `POST`-запрос с особыми данными. Вопрос: как отобразить в iframe страницу, запросив ее по особому `url` и отправив параметры методом `POST`?
Если имеет значение, то движок только webkit, на остальных не важно, будет ли работать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Делаем промежуточную страницу, путь к ней и вставляем в src фрейма
2. На самой странице делаем post запрос скриптом, например

---

```
$.post('test.html', function(data) {    
   $('body').html(data);
});
```

Естественно для этого подключив в промежуточную страницу jquery

**UPD:** А ещё лучше поставить на страницу форму со скрытыми полями для параметров и отправить её скриптом. Тогда содержимое не будет подгружаться аяксом и не будет проблем с работой скриптов на конечной странице, плюс не нужно подключать jquery

```
<form action='test.html'>
     <input type='hidden' name='param1' value='123'/>
</form>
<script>
    document.forms[0].submit()
</script>
```

Comment: Да! Интересная идея. Попробую.

Comment: Точняк! Красивая идея. Спасибо!